# Atomic Update for postgresql table

Tags: python, postgresql, atomic

**Background**

I have a simple function that makes an update to my table. Any time i execute my script `foo_script.py` i call this function `set_status` to create a time stamp. Once i am done with the process i call the function `remove_status` to make the entry in the table NULL.

I also have a wrapper script called `db.py` that lets me execute sql statements hence in my code i am using `db.execute()` but that is not relevant to my problem here.

The idea is that  `foo_script.py` can not run concurrently.

**Code**

```
def set_status() -> None:
    db.execute(
        ENVIRONMENT=db.get_environment(),
        sql="UPDATE my_table SET status_process = NOW()",
    )

def remove_status() -> None:
    db.execute(
        ENVIRONMENT=db.get_environment(),
        sql="UPDATE my_table SET status_process = NULL",
    )
```

**ISSUE**

Unfortunately the script `foo_script.py` can be accidentally run by 2 or more. I want to avoid any race conditions. How can i ensure the queries i make are atomic. I am new to sql and i am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: have you considered using a [lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-lock.html)

Comment: ah this would work so if i understood correct, lock would ensure when i am making update to that row no one else can make update to it. i think i can accept your answer if you paste it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a typical application for [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS).

If you use them, you don't need to lock an object in the database to synchronize operations. Also, advisory locks can be independent of transactions, so you don't have to have long database transactions with all their associated unpleasantness.

To grab the lock, run

```
SELECT pg_advisory_lock (42);
```

and to release it, run

```
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(42);
```

42 is the lock number; you are of course free to choose a different one.

Comment: is there a time stamp associated with this?

Comment: No; I didn't know you needed a timestamp, I thought you wanted to synchronize processing. Perhaps I misunderstood the question, feel free to edit it and explain what this timestamp would be used for.

Comment: Sure so in my application i basically `set_status` when i start running some process script. Now say for some reason it crashes. if i try to run it again i will not be able to because my script would only `remove_status` only at the end of my process script. However knowing at what time i started the process script gives me more information than a plain lock. So as such if you can tell me how i can make my existing query more atomic it would help a lot.

Comment: Any advisory lock will automatically go away if the database session is terminated.